# Open LDAP installation failed

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have tried this way.

```
sudo apt-get install -y slapd
```

But it is showing error. I am using Ubuntu 20.4.0.2

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
   libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   slapd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,397 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package slapd.
(Reading database ... 203087 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../slapd_2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking slapd (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7) ...
Setting up slapd (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7) ...
slappasswd: /usr/local/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by 
slappasswd)
slappasswd: /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by 
slappasswd)
slappasswd: symbol lookup error: slappasswd: undefined symbol: ldap_pvt_sasl_mutex_unlock, 
version OPENLDAP_2.4_2
   Creating initial configuration... Loading the initial configuration from the ldif file () 
failed with
the following error while running slapadd:
   slapadd: /usr/local/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by 
slapadd)
   slapadd: /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by 
slapadd)
   slapadd: symbol lookup error: slapadd: undefined symbol: ldap_pvt_sasl_mutex_unlock, 
version OPENLDAP_2.4_2
dpkg: error processing package slapd (--configure):
  installed slapd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-6) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
  slapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already have a SLAPD installation done from source. Please purge that and try again

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1151438)

Comment: @zx485 sounds for me it's a valid answer

Comment: @αғsнιη: Reconsidering, you may be right. I'd like to take back my vote, but I don't know how. But I guess the 5th vote will correct that.